# Showing the status of the battery on a card reader in my app using the Handpoint Android API

Tags: android

I'm developing a pos-application using the *[Handpoint](https://www.handpoint.com/en/) Android API* (*v.3.2.2*).

I want to show the status of the battery on the card reader in my app.

I've looked at the [provided documentation](https://www.handpoint.com/docs/device/Android/), I know I can access the `BatteryStatus` property in the `DeviceStatus` object, but it is unclear to me *where*, or *how* I can access the `DeviceStatus` object itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The BatteryStatus property

In version *3.2.2* of the *Handpoint Android API* (as well as the current version, *3.2.4*), the battery status property is accessible through the object `DeviceStatus`, i.e. `deviceStatus.getBatteryStatus();`. The `DeviceStatus` object is sent with the `TransactionResult` object as well as the `StatusInfo` object.

#### Object structure

The object structure is as follows:

`TransactionResult` → `DeviceStatus` →  `BatteryStatus`

`StatusInfo` → `DeviceStatus` → `BatteryStatus`

The `DeviceStatus` object is sent from the SDK with every `currentTransactionStatus(StatusInfo statusInfo, Device device)` and the `endOfTransaction(TransactionResult transactionResult, Device device)` events.

#### Accessing the BatterStatus property from a currentTranscationStatus event

To access the `BatteryStatus` property from a `currentTransactionStatus` event, simply do:

```
@Override
public void endOfTransaction(TransactionResult transactionResult, Device device)
{
    transactionResult.getDeviceStatus().getBatteryStatus();
}

@Override
public void currentTransactionStatus(StatusInfo statusInfo, Device device)
{
    statusInfo.getDeviceStatus().getBatteryStatus();
}
```